# highlight for dragEnter

Tags: javascript, html

I am performing drap and swap in javascript. I want to highlight when dragged element is placed on top of other draggable elements. For this I am using **dragEnter** and **dragLeave** events. But these are not working as expected. Here I have attached [stakblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-dnunuz?file=index.html,styles.css,dnd.js) link for the sample. Can anyone help me to fix this issue? I want a element to be in highlighted state when the dragged element on top of it.

[image]

In the above example I can drag A to the others(It can be B, C or D).  when I dragged A and move to C(B or D) means C(B or D) should be highlighed.

Comment: Which element do you want to highlight? Dragged element or the element on which it is dropped?

Comment: I want latter element to be highlighted i.e., element on which it is dropped.

Comment: I checked the fiddle when the dragged element is being on top of the dropped element, the dropped element is highlighted with a dashed border but the border removes soon. Is this what you are talking about?

Comment: @NehaSoni yes Currently the highlight is ephemeral. I want it when the dragged element remains in the droppable element.

Comment: Not sure but the problem is inside the HTML. When I removed this code from all 4 draggable divs, things are working fine.  `<div>Content <div>Data</div></div>`

Comment: yes removing those child elements won't be an ideal case because practically dragging on single div element is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `this` with `lastEle` here:

```js
function handleDragEnter(e) {
  //lastEle ? this.classList.remove('over'): '';
  lastEle ? lastEle.classList.remove('over'): '';
  this.classList.add('over');
  lastEle = this;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  var dragSrcEl = null;
  let lastElem;

  function handleDragStart(e) {
    this.style.opacity = '0.4';

    dragSrcEl = this;

    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);
  }

  function handleDragOver(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';

    return false;
  }

  function handleDragEnter(e) {
    lastElem ? lastElem.classList.remove('over') : '';

    this.classList.add('over');

    lastElem = this;
  }

  function handleDragLeave(e) {
    // this.classList.remove('over');
  }

  function handleDrop(e) {
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
      e.stopPropagation(); // stops the browser from redirecting.
    }

    if (dragSrcEl != this) {
      dragSrcEl.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
      this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
    }

    return false;
  }

  function handleDragEnd(e) {
    this.style.opacity = '1';

    items.forEach(function (item) {
      item.classList.remove('over');
    });
  }

  let items = document.querySelectorAll('.container .box');
  items.forEach(function (item) {
    item.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
    item.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false);
    item.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
    item.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
    item.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
    item.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
  });
});
```

Try this changes. It will work.

Comment: Can you highlight your changes because it didn't work for me.

Comment: Yes.


i) Declare one variable let lastElem;

ii) And add below code in handleDragEnter function

lastElem ? lastElem.classList.remove('over') : '';

this.classList.add('over');

lastElem = this;

iii) Comment the code in handleDragLeave function.

That's it.

Comment: please post your answer as text and not as an image.

Comment: Updated please check.

Comment: Instead of *"Try this buddy"* or *"This will work"* - try to explain in a paragraph or two the changes you made. And, it's not necessary to waste 160KB of silica...